# MongoDB same index error with different strings

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I created custom unique text index, but I have one problem with it. It thinks that 'foo-1' and 'foo-2' are the same, even though they are not. Is there a way to fix or bypass this?

Note: I want text indexes because they are simple and human readable unlike _id. Numbers are also not an option.

Here is how it looks like in MongoDB Compass:
[image]

Comment: Are you sure text is the correct type? Such an index is for natural language text that is tokenized. A unique constraint is rather uncommon for such a field. You should read the MongoDB index documentation carefully. Most likely you just want a regular field index.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I'm relatively new to MongoDB. Could you help me out with creating the index? @Robert

Comment: This has related rules: [Text Index Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#restrictions).

Comment: Just use a different index type, text is not the one you want. I don't know how the regular index is named in Compass, I don't use this bloated tool. Please read the manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/

Comment: Oh, there are only 4 indexes in compass. I'll check out the link you've sent.